# How to create child with autoid in Firebase with Angularfire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

```
af.database.object('item').set({ name: newName });
```

I can save value in a known node with this method in AngularFire2.

I want to know how to save in a unique node each time like this.

In Swift there is something like this:

```
node.childByAutoId().setValue([key: value]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is no one liner for this.
In AngularFire2 the push method is only available on FirebaseListObservables but not FirebaseObjectObservable. So here is a small component for demonstrating this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
    selector: 'auto',
    template: `
    <ul>
        <li class="text" *ngFor="let p of person | async">
            {{p.name}}
         </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" #newname placeholder="Name" />
    <br />
    <button (click)="save(newname.value)">Set Name</button>
    `
})

export class AutoComponent {
    person: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
    constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
        this.person = af.database.list('person')
    }
    save(newName: string) {
        this.person.push({ "name": newName });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use .push?

```
node.child('items').push({ key: value })
```

Or do you mean you want to save a node with that key? If so then do this:

```
node.child('items').child(key).set(value);
```

Comment: This is how we save in Javascript with Firebase client. I wanted to know how to save with angularfire2 specifically! :) and your first code is how wanted to store data. On a node with auto generated id.

Comment: Can you not still use firebase.database().ref() in angular 2? My suggestion does not involve angularfire2.

Comment: I am not sure about that! Since I am using TypeScript  , not sure how to use typeDefinitions of javascript libraries in TypeScript. If you can show me, it would be great.

Comment: You can still use plain old javascript. firebase.database().ref().child('person').push({ name: newName })

Comment: @MathewBerg You've ever tried doing that, as in calling `firebase.something` in your component before?

Comment: @Rexford yes but make sure you import firebase first: `import * as firebase from 'firebase';`